# adding newline to xml file while creating using libxml1.2.3

Tags: libxml2

How can one add new line using libxml1.2.3. in xml file.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Lines outside of XML tags are ignored.

Comment: Add a newline where?  You need to give more information about what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Darin what i mean is while writing i want to maintain a tree structure which i have created while writing a file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xml indent and newline for new child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30500827/xml-indent-and-newline-for-new-child)

Comment: @DarinDimitrov sometimes you need to compare two XML files with a 'diff' tool. They don't handle 12,000-character single lines very well.

Answer (score 0):

When you dump xml output use [`xmlSaveFormatFileEnc`](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlSaveFormatFileEnc) instead of [`xmlSaveFileEnc`](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlSaveFileEnc). In general use *format* family of functions, like they do in [tree2.c](http://www.xmlsoft.org/examples/index.html#tree2.c) example.