# xml indent and newline for new child

Tags: c, xml, libxml2

I have a xml file that looks like a following.

```
<root>
    <children>
        <foo1 val="23"/>
        <foo2 val="14"/>
    </children>
</root>
```

I wish to add a new child with name *foo* to the  node using the functions *xmlNewChild()* followed by *xmlNewProp()*. I would like to generate something like the following.

```
<root>
    <children>
        <foo1 val="23"/>
        <foo2 val="14"/>
        <foo3 val="5"/>
    </children>
</root>
```

However, I always end up with the following.

```
<root>
    <children>
        <foo1 val="23"/>
        <foo2 val="14"/>
    <foo3 val="5"/></children>
</root>
```

I do understand that libxml2 does not favor white spaces by default. However, is there a way to achieve the result I want? I need to get those tabs in front and newlines in the end for the newly added child.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that the XML structure actually looks like this:

```
<root>
    [TEXT:"\n    "]
    <children>
        [TEXT:"\n        "]
        <foo1 val="23"/>
        [TEXT:"\n        "]
        <foo2 val="14"/>
        [TEXT:"\n    "]
    </children>
    [TEXT:"\n"]
</root>
```

If you just add an extra element node at the end of `children`, you can see that what you get is inevitable (as there is no text node to carry a newline and the desired indentation between `foo3` and `children`).

You need to edit the final text node inside `children` (the one immediately after `foo2`) to give it an extra indent, then append your new node, then append a new text node to indent `</children>`. Alternately, you can insert a text node identical to previous text nodes inside `children` and then your new element node just before the final text node in `children`. Both should give you the same result, the one you need:

```
<root>
    [TEXT:"\n    "]
    <children>
        [TEXT:"\n        "]
        <foo1 val="23"/>
        [TEXT:"\n        "]
        <foo2 val="14"/>
        [TEXT:"\n        "]
        <foo3 val="5"/>
        [TEXT:"\n    "]
    </children>
    [TEXT:"\n"]
</root>
```

Another approach is to have libxml2 autoindent the output for you. This will destroy existing indentation and redo it from scratch. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4537132/240443) is a relevant answer.

Comment: I realized that the `xmlKeepBlanksDefault(0);` needed to be set before parsing the file. It does auto indent for us, which would be good enough for my purpose. But definitely text method is worth a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `xmlTextWriterSetIndent`

Ref : http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlwriter.html#xmlTextWriterSetIndent